# is there a specific better algorithm to solve this problem faster way

Tags: javascript, algorithm, dom, optimization

I am trying to iterate through the body tag and all its children deep like if one of the children of the body contains other children, I want to be to reach those as well, I am trying to come up better and faster algorithm can anyone help to come up a better one other than mine?

```
<body>
  <div class = "header-section">
    <header class = "header-himself">
      <div class = "nav-section">
        <nav class = "nav-himself">
          <div class = "list-section-left">
            <ul class = "list-itself-left">
              <li>Darster</li>
              <li>Company</li>
              <li>Safety</li>
              <li>Help</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class = "list-section-right">
          <ul class="list-itself-right">
            <li>Service</li>
              <li>Dart In</li>
              <li>Dart Out</li>
          </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>
  </div>
</body>


var target = document.querySelector('body');


function getChildren(target) {
     
    if(target.children.length === 0) {
        return;
    }

    for(var i = 0; i < target.children.length; i++) {
        console.log(target.children[i].tagName);
        getChildren(target.children[i]);
    }
}



getChildren(target);
```

Comment: Seems like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You'd very rarely, if ever, need to visit every DOM node ever. What exactly are you trying to do? Perhaps this is the wrong approach.

Comment: I want to get all the children of the children inside the parent which is the body at this moment.

Comment: @AliayubAli, the first comment is asking you *why* you want to get all the children of the children, ...etc. Your comment is not explaining more than what you already said in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a very simple tree walker:

```js
const walkDOMTree = (visitor, types = [Node.ELEMENT_NODE]) => (node) => {
  if (types == "*" || types .includes (node .nodeType)) {
    visitor .visit (node)
  }
  node .childNodes .forEach (walkDOMTree (visitor, types))
  return visitor
} 

const visitor = (captured = []) => ({
  visit: (node) => {if (node .nodeName == 'LI') captured .push (node.textContent)},
  captured
})


const v = visitor ()
walkDOMTree (v) (document)
console .log ('LI content: ', v .captured)
```

```html
<div class = "header-section">
  <header class = "header-himself">
    <div class = "nav-section">
      <nav class = "nav-himself">
        <div class = "list-section-left">
          <ul class = "list-itself-left">
            <li>Darster</li>
            <li>Company</li>
            <li>Safety</li>
            <li>Help</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class = "list-section-right">
          <ul class="list-itself-right">
            <li>Service</li>
            <li>Dart In</li>
            <li>Dart Out</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
</div>
```

**`walkDOMTree`** accepts a `visitor` -- simply an object with a `visit` method -- and optionally an array of the [nodeTypes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType) you care to visit.  (If you supply `'*'`, it will visit all node types, including attributes, comments, CDATA, etc.  By default, it will visit only elements.)  It returns a function that takes a DOM node and then recursively calls the visitor's `visit` function on that node and each of its descendants in document order.

I would often write this to accept a simple function, `visit`, rather than an object that has such a function.  But this version makes it easier for your visitor to do useful things like collecting some data, as shown here, where our tree-walker visits all elements, and the visitor collects the text of all the `LI` elements.

---

However, I wouldn't likely use such a function nowadays, as browsers already supply a built-in [TreeWalker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TreeWalker) API.  If this is just for learning, then please feel free to play with the above, but for production work, use the standards!

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the `*` selector.

```
var allBodyNodes = document.body.querySelectorAll('*');
```

Comment: I will appreciate the algorithm not the shortest path scunliffe thank you

Comment: Who says this is giving the "shortest path", @AliayubAli? It is not.

Comment: I mean I want to see the actual steps of the algorithm.

Comment: Ah, OK, so you're just curious to find the fastest algorithm that walks through all nodes in the body... not an easy solution. (you may want to update your original question to indicate this). This might be hard to get a universal solution for as each page may vary (deep vs. wide) at any given node in the tree.

Comment: @scunliffe "*This might be hard to get a universal solution for as each page may vary (deep vs. wide) at any given node in the tree.*"? Tree traversal is a very well understood topic. DOM trees are special there. With that said, the topic *so well* understood that it's pretty much given for free in a browser environment. For example [TreeWalker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TreeWalker). *If talking about DOM*, then it's exceptionally unlikely that a tree traversal algorithm needs to be implemented. If OP's interested in general tree traversal, then the DOM is a red herring.